# Android GetResourceId not always getting the ID

Tags: android, android-animation, android-resources

Why is my custom control resolving an animation resource from one view, but not the other?

I've got a custom control that inherits from `TextView`. In my Initialize method, I've got the following.

```csharp
    private void Initialize(IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        var a = _context.Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.FontIconTextView, 0, 0);

        // work with animations
        _animationResource = a.GetResourceId(Resource.Styleable.FontIconTextView_Animation, 0);
        _animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(_context, _animationResource);
        Animate = a.GetBoolean(Resource.Styleable.FontIconTextView_Animate, false);

        Initialize();
    }
```

I have a resource that defines all of my `local` attributes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="FontIconTextView">
    <attr name="Animate" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="Animation" format="integer" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then on my splash screen I have the following Control that **IS WORKING** as expected

```xml
  <FontIconTextView
      android:id="@+id/Splashscreen_QuickSync_Icon"
      android:text="@string/icon_refresh"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:clickable="false"
      android:textColor="#00bbe6"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      local:Animate="true"
      local:Animation="@anim/sync_rotate" />
```

the splash screen loads, and `_animationResource = 2130968576`

However, I have similar code on my RootView

```xml
  <FontIconTextView
      android:id="@+id/RootView_QuickSync_Icon"
        android:text="@string/icon_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        local:MvxBind="Command QuickSyncCommand; Animate Animate"
        local:Animation="@anim/sync_rotate"/>
```

and when I run it up,  `_animationResource = 0` and I get the following exception

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class FontIconTextView
>   Android.Views.InflateException: Loading...
>   The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Now I'm not sure what the difference is between the two, but this doesn't make sense that I can access `@anim/sync_rotate` from the SplashScreen and not the RootView.

Comment: Not sure the reason for the problem, and a definitive answer as to why would be greatly appreciated, however I have solved the issue but doing an if check `if(_animationResource != 0) _animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(_context, _animationResource);` and then a similar if check that `if(_animation != null) StartAnimation(_animation);`